# Amazon SP-API - Reports API => processingStatus is always `CANCELLED`

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to make a call on Amazon Reports API of SP-API using postman. The issue is processingStatus is always `CANCELLED`.

Actually I am following this [tutorial](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/reports-api-v2021-06-30-tutorial-request-a-report) and as explained in the tutorial, there are 3 steps.

`Step 1 : request a report`, I can request a report of type `GET_FLAT_FILE_ACTIONABLE_ORDER_DATA_SHIPPING` and get the `reportId` as response successfully.

`Step 2 : Confirm that the report processing is complete`, in this step, I get `"processingStatus": "CANCELLED"` every time I checked.

Request Body : [image]

Response : [image]

Documentation suggests

1. to periodically call the getReport operation, passing the reportId value from the previous step, until the processingStatus value in the response indicates that processing has ended.
2. Here are the processingStatus values that confirm that processing has ended:

CANCELLED - The report was cancelled. There are two ways a report can be cancelled: an explicit cancellation request before the report starts processing, or an automatic cancellation if there is no data to return.

But in my case, I did not request to cancel the report nor I can see unshipped orders via GUI.

So why is processingStatus always cancelled?
did I miss any steps nor anything?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call that api, you need the restricted data role on your dev account. You would need to make a call to the restricted data token api to get an RDT first, and then use that token to make your call to get the report.

[Endpoints that have restricted access](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/direct-to-consumer-shipping-restricted-role)

[RDT api documentation](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/tokens-api-v2021-03-01-reference)

Comment: Sorry for late reply,
When requesting to get RDT for resource path => `/reports/2021-06-30/reports` and request method `POST`, I always got exception.

Comment: We don't need RDT when creating report according to the list given [here](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/tokens-api-use-case-guide#restricted-operations).

Comment: In the link you send, it lists the report that you are requesting under restricted reports. https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/tokens-api-use-case-guide#restricted-operations:~:text=GET_FLAT_FILE_ACTIONABLE_ORDER_DATA_SHIPPING

Comment: Yes, you are right. It said we need RDT for `in a call to the getReportDocument operation, you must pass in an RDT with the call` 

[Workflow](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/reports-api-v2021-06-30-tutorial-request-a-report#tutorial-request-and-retrieve-a-report) is such that 
1. Call the createReport
2. Periodically poll the report processing
3. Call the getReportDocument operation

Report processing always get `CANCELLED ` at step 2 and we have to provide RDT at step 3.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I don't know what the problem is then. Are you sure you have data for the dates selected? Can you try different dates to test?

Comment: I just thought that API got some issue that we can't see.